# Running muliple profiles in maven to build zip but facing some dependency issue

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying create 2 zip files one for testing and other for production.
pom.xml looks like below.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>a.abc</groupId>
                <artifactId>abc1</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>a.abc</groupId>
                <artifactId>abc2</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>a.abc</groupId>
                <artifactId>abc3</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>b.xyz</groupId>
                <artifactId>xyz1</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>b.xyz</groupId>
                <artifactId>xyz2</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>b.xyz</groupId>
                <artifactId>xyz3</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <finalName>app-${project.version}</finalName>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
                            <!-- <finalName>${project.name}</finalName> -->
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>app-package-test</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/test-descriptor.xml</descriptor>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>

            </build>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>a.abc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>abc1</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>a.abc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>abc2</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>a.abc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>abc3</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
                            <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>app-package-production</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/production-descriptor.xml</descriptor>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>b.xyz</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xyz1</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>b.xyz</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xyz2</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>b.xyz</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xyz3</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

But when I run ***mvn clean install*** it will build both profile since

```
<activation>
       <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
</activation>
```

But final bundled zip contains both dependencies of profile ***test*** and ***production***

I need zip generated by profile ***test*** to have dependencies related to ***test*** profile and zip generated by profile ***production*** to have dependencies related to ***production*** profile.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: If both profiles are active, then it is rather logical that both profiles dependencies are included in the ZIP, as your build by default activates both profiles. To get the ZIP with only production dependencies, just launch `mvn clean install -Pproduction`